# Solaris 10 - password complexity not working

Tags: solaris, passwd

I have been trying to enable password complexity variables on Solaris 10 by editing the /etc/default/passwd file but none of my changes are taking effect (I'm still able to set passwords that violate the rules I am trying to implement).

I've tried an O/S reboot after the changes but that had no effect.

The variables I am trying to change/enabled within the /etc/default/passwd file:

```
MAXWEEKS=12
PASSLENGTH=8
MINALPHA=1
MINNNALPHA=1
MINUPPER=1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would stop it working entirely, but you appear to have a typo: MINNNALPHA=1 should be MINNONALPHA=1. We use this functionality with no issues... BTW no reboot is necessary, changes take effect immediately...